# Double click the element with style "-webkit-app-region: drag;" to maximize the window leads to an error that "maximize" button does not change

Tags: vue.js, electron

I'm using electron to develop a software. I have a frameless window. I create a titlebar myself using css code "-webkit-app-region: drag;", and I have a "maximize"/"unmaximize" button. The question is that, when I double click the title-bar, the window maximizes, but the "maximize"/"unmaximize" button does not change. I've tried to use ipc to communicate, but there's still a problem. The problem is that after I click the 'maximize' button, the window maximizes, but when I double click the "drag region", it triggers 'maximize' signal of the window. As we know, a normal software should trigger 'unmaximize' when I double click the "drag region".

main.js:
`

```
  win.on('maximize', () => {
    win.webContents.send('maximize-app-window')
  })
  win.on('unmaximize', () => {
    win.webContents.send('unmaximize-app-window')
  })
```

`

renderer.js:
`

```
  <div v-if="maximizeType === 'maximize'"
      class="icon-checkbox-unchecked" @click="maximizeAppWindow()"></div>
  <div v-else
      class="icon-window-restore-o" @click="unmaximizeAppWindow()"></div>
```

```
...(vue component code)
  data: function () {
    return {
      maximizeType: 'maximize'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    maximizeAppWindow () {
      this.maximizeType = 'unmaximize'
      ipcRenderer.send('maximize-app-window')
    },
    unmaximizeAppWindow () {
      this.maximizeType = 'maximize'
      ipcRenderer.send('unmaximize-app-window')
    },
  },
```

```
...
mounted() {
  ipcRenderer.on('maximize-app-window', (event) => {
    this.maximizeType = 'unmaximize'
  })
  ipcRenderer.on('unmaximize-app-window', (event) => {
    this.maximizeType = 'maximize'
  })
}
```

`